# QTimer timouts immediately after start

Tags: c++, qt

I have encountered some problem that I seem not be able to solve. It may be some silly mistake. I have a class that runs another class's method in a separate QThread 5000msec after the method fires a signal. At least this would be the idea but this is not happening.

```
#ifndef MOVEME_MPOINTER_HPP
#define MOVEME_MPOINTER_HPP

#include <Windows.h>
#include <WindowsX.h>

#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QAction>
#include <QCursor>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QRect>

#include "worker.hpp"

namespace Ui {
    class MoveMe_MPointer;
}

class MoveMe_MPointer : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MoveMe_MPointer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MoveMe_MPointer();

    virtual bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result);

public slots:
    void resetTimer();
    void closeApplication();

private:
    QSharedPointer<QIcon>           icon;
    QSharedPointer<QSystemTrayIcon> systemtray;

    QSharedPointer<QThread> workerThread;
    QSharedPointer<Worker>  workerObject;
    QSharedPointer<QTimer>  workerTimer;

    QSharedPointer<QCursor> cursor;
};

#endif // MOVEME_MPOINTER_HPP
```

The implementation of the relevant methods are as follows:

```
MoveMe_MPointer::MoveMe_MPointer(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    icon        = QSharedPointer<QIcon>(new QIcon("://appicon"));
    systemtray  = QSharedPointer<QSystemTrayIcon>(new QSystemTrayIcon);

    // Create cursor
    cursor = QSharedPointer<QCursor>(new QCursor(Qt::ForbiddenCursor));

    systemtray->setIcon(*icon.data());
    systemtray->setVisible(true);

    workerThread = QSharedPointer<QThread>(new QThread());
    workerObject = QSharedPointer<Worker> (new Worker ());

    workerObject->setX(100);
    workerObject->setY(100);

    workerObject->moveToThread(workerThread.data());

    workerTimer = QSharedPointer<QTimer>(new QTimer());

    QObject::connect(workerThread.data(), SIGNAL(started()), workerObject.data(), SLOT(Work()));
    QObject::connect(workerTimer.data(), SIGNAL(timeout()), workerObject.data(), SLOT(Work()));
    QObject::connect(workerObject.data(), SIGNAL(Done()), this, SLOT(resetTimer()));

    RegisterHotKey((HWND) winId(), 0, MOD_CONTROL, 0x51);
    RegisterHotKey((HWND) winId(), 1, MOD_CONTROL | MOD_SHIFT, 0x4D);
}

void MoveMe_MPointer::resetTimer() {
    qDebug() << "START";
    workerTimer->start(5000);
    qDebug() << "STOP";
}
```

The underlying class:

```
#ifndef WORKER_HPP
#define WORKER_HPP

#include <Windows.h>

#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QObject>
#include <QCursor>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    int     x;
    int     y;
    bool    stop;

public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);
    void setX(const int x);
    void setY(const int y);
    void Stop();

signals:
    void Done();

public slots:
    void Work();

private:
    void doWork();

};

#endif // WORKER_HPP
```

With the implementation as follows:

```
#include "worker.hpp"

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
    stop = false;
}

void Worker::setX(const int x) {
    this->x = x;
}

void Worker::setY(const int y) {
    this->y = y;
}

void Worker::Stop() {
    stop = true;
}

void Worker::Work() {
    doWork();
}

void Worker::doWork() {
    int _x = 50;

    INPUT input;
    ZeroMemory(&input, sizeof(input));
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.mouseData = 0;
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    for (int dx = 0; dx < _x && !stop; ++dx) {
        input.mi.dx = +1;
        input.mi.dy = +1;
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
        QThread::msleep(10);
    }
    QThread::msleep(100);
    for (int dx = 0; dx < _x && !stop; ++dx) {
        input.mi.dx = -1;
        input.mi.dy = -1;
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
        QThread::msleep(10);
    }
    QThread::msleep(100);

    emit Done();
}
```

Whenever my application receives the Done signal my resetTimer slot gets executed but the interesting part is. It times out immediately and does not wait even a second. What am i missing?

Comment: How do you conclude that the timer fires instantly?

Comment: oh sorry yeah. as you can see that the timeout signal of my timer is connected to the slot of the workerObject. When my resettimer finishes the slot gets immediately called.